# My searchable Dropdown list view is not working asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Him I downloaded from Nugget package "bootstrap.Chosen". also I was using "@Html.DropDownListFor". also I setup id for jQuery. Everything looks correct but it cannot get Search bar in my dropdown list. My code is below.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MessageTo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MessageTo,(SelectList)ViewBag.Employeelist, new { id = 
               "Dropdown" }) //I setup Id for using jQuery.
        </div>
        </div>

        @section Scripts{
          <script>
              $(function () {
                $("#Dropdown").chosen();
            });
          </script>
          }
```

I also setup Layout page

```
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
      @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
      <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't know why I cannot use Search bar in my dropdown list.

Comment: can you inspect element with your browser to double check his id, I am more familiar with vbhtml, but i think your dropdown id is MessageTo, so you script should follow, let me know if i made mistake

Comment: You mean my dropdowm id has to be same as element which is   In script?